# Mongoengine DictField() not shown in _fields

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following django class in my models:

```
class mongoMedia(Document)
        ....
        category         = StringField()
        hough_distance   = DictField()
```

After populating the collection with some data I need to update the 'hough_distance' field.
I have tried something like:

```
media_object = mongoMedia.objects.get(sql_id=100)
media_object.update(set__category='catX') #it works
media_object.update(set__hough_distance={'k1': v1, 'k2': v2}) #does not work
```

The second update obviously does not work because 'hough_distance' is not listed among the '_fields' of my 'media_object'. The error is:

```
InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "hough_distance"
```

I have also tried:

```
mongoMedia._get_collection().update({'id': media_obj.id }, {'$set': {'hough_distance.%s' % (hough_distance.distance): object_compare} } )
```

which does not save anything in the collection.

While this works in mongodb shell:

```
db.mongo_media.update( { '_id': media_object._id }, { $set: { 'hough_distance': { 'k1': v1} } } )
```

How can I "translate" the above in a valid Django syntax and why the DictField() is not listed in the object '_fields' attribute?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Let me put it other way:
How can I update a MongoDB dictionary in Django?

Comment: What does this output? mongoMedia()._fields

Comment: The output is too long therefore I will paste just part of it. In fact every field is listed except the ones which are DictField() type.                               {'category': <mongoengine.fields.ListField object at 0x0365E370>, 'sql_id': <mongoengine.fields.IntField object at 0x0365E110>, 'description': <mongoengine.fields.StringField object at 0x0365E2D0>,

Comment: What version of MongoEngine?